# Regex to get <a href> from a string in java

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have

```
<img class="size-full wp-image-10225" alt="animals" src="abc.jpg"> blah blah blah&nbsp;
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant">elephant is an animal</a>&nbsp;blah
```

I want a regex to give me the output :

```
blah blah blah <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant">elephant is an animal</a> blah
```

without the `&nbsp;`. I can do `str.replace("&nbsp;","")` separately, but how do I get the string starting from `blah blah...` until `blah` (which includes link tag).

Comment: you must remove the `img` tag seperately. Do you only need the a-Tag? That works with RegExpr. If you like to get the other text before and after the tag, here you have problems. Why you dont remove easily unneeded tags?

Comment: I do need the text before the tag as well. So basically I cant say StringUtils.removeHTMLTags() as this removes all the tags and I want the html tag. so basically what I'm thinking is to locate the first ">" before ahref and then capture the text from there till </a> ( inclusive)

Comment: _Sees regex and HTML in title_ "http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2846923."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
^<[^>]*>\s*|&nbsp;
```

Java escaped:

```
^<[^>]*>\\s*|&nbsp;
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/hL2pB1)

`^<[^>]*>\\s*` will match the first `img` tag and any following spaces. Then replace the `&nbsp;`. The replacement string is `""`.

You might want to use a proper HTML parser though, since it'll be less likely to break.

Comment: hey thanks Jerry. I don't get the java escaped part though. So should I do something like this: str.replace(^<[^>]*>\s*|&nbsp;,"")

Comment: @user3298846 Use the escaped version in Java. :)